# A good lambda for array length?

Tags: java, arrays, lambda

Is there an elegant lambda for an array length? Something like a method reference, just not for a method? Array `length` is more like a public final field.

From a jagged 2D array (`Object[][]`) I wanted to find the longest inner array. It’s easy enough:

```
    OptionalInt width = Stream.of(myJaggedArray).mapToInt(line -> line.length).max();
```

I’m just wondering if I’m missing something when I cannot find better than `line -> line.length`. I had thought `Object[]::length` might work, but it gives “The type Object[] does not define length(Object[]) that is applicable here”. I have searched the web without finding an alternative.

I can live happily with what I have. Maybe it’s just a special thing for arrays caused by the length not coming from a method. Thought it was worth asking.

Comment: There is nothing special about it... there are no field references in Java.

Comment: For working code, codereview.stackexchange.com would be a better place. But given the fact how simple things are here, I would rather not use the method reference notation here.

Comment: This is easier on the eyes than something with a class name and two colons.

Comment: Write your own `arrayLength` function then referring it in the `mapToInt` call, or just shorten your lambda parameter name to `l`: `l -> l.length`. :)

Comment: No, there isn't, but you can implement your own method if you want and use method reference. But it would be longer than just `l -> l.length`

Comment: Thanks, everyone, for your positive and enlightening comments. @MarkoTopolnik, you describe very clearly why I cannot do what I dreamt of: Java has method references, it hasn’t got field references (no matter if `length` really is a field or just looks like one). In spite of the creative suggestions, I’ll prefer to stay with what I have.

Answer (score 7):

Summarizing up in addition to my comment on shortening the lambda parameter name and using a static method reference, I would give four solutions in total:

## Shortening the lambda parameter name

This is the most straight-forward and natural way I can think of, and you would probably stick with it as it's nothing wrong with it:

```
Stream.of(myJaggedArray).mapToInt(l -> l.length).max()
```

I don't think that you would like any of the solutions below, but let them be all in the collection.

## Using an array length static method reference

```
Stream.of(myJaggedArray).mapToInt(ArrayLength::length).max()
```

where `ArrayLength#length` is very simple:

```
private static <T> int length(final T[] array) {
    return array.length;
}
```

## Creating a simple array wrapper to align with method references

Since the `length` property is not a real field in Java, and it's definitely not a method, you might also want to wrap an array into a simple wrapper (using just `T` not bloating to 8 primitive wrapper implementations).

```
public final class ArrayWrapper<T> {

    private final T[] array;

    private ArrayWrapper(final T[] array) { this.array = array; }

    public static <T> ArrayWrapper<T> wrap(final T[] array) { return new ArrayWrapper<>(array); }

    public T get(int i) { return array[i]; }

    public void set(final int i, final T e) { array[i] = e; }

    public int length() { return array.length; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object o) { ... }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() { ... }

}
```

Thus you can write then:

```
Stream.of(wrap(myJaggedArray)).mapToInt(ArrayWrapper::length).max()
```

## Your own stream factory method to produce a stream of `ArrayWrapper<T>`

A stream factory method might encapsulate the `ArrayWrapper#wrap` method itself:

```
StreamWrapper.of(myJaggedArray).mapToInt(ArrayWrapper::length).max()
```

And then in `StreamWrapper`:

```
public static <T> Stream<ArrayWrapper<T>> of(final T[] array) {
    return Stream.of(ArrayWrapper.wrap(array));
}
```

I would recommend none of the latter three solutions, and let them be just example workarounds.

Your lambda expression `line -> line.length` is really good and really idiomatic.